# actix-web client handle payload as stream

Tags: rust, client, response, payload, actix-web

Simple http client with actix in rust. Get response from server, can handle header. But when try to handle payload my understanding of rust fails.
My wish is to handle the payload byte by byte, to get huge streams and chunked data. Simple body() solution works fine. But how to get bytes out of payload. It seems to impl Stream, so fn size_hint() is accessable but poll_next from Stream by Decompresser impl Decoder impl Stream not.

main.rs

```
use actix::prelude::*;
use actix_http::encoding::{Decoder};
use actix_web::{HttpMessage,client::ClientBuilder,dev::Payload,http::{Version, StatusCode},web::Bytes};

use futures::future::{TryFutureExt};
use futures_core::stream::Stream;

use std::pin::Pin;
use std::boxed::Box;
use std::task::{Context, Poll};

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() {
    const URL : [&str; 2] = ["..",".."];

    let client = ClientBuilder::new()
        .disable_timeout()
        .disable_redirects()
        .header("User-Agent", "actix-web/3.0")
        .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br, chunked")
        .header("Connection", "keepalive")
        .header("DNT", "1")
        .max_http_version( Version::HTTP_2 )
        .finish();

    // Create request builder and send request
    let response = 
    client.get(URL[0]).send().map_err(|err|{
        println!("Error on send {:?}",err);
    });

    match response.await{
        Ok( mut v) => {         
            println!("encoding: {:?}",v.encoding());
            println!("content type: {:?}",v.content_type());
            println!("mime type: {:?}",v.mime_type());
            println!("chunked: {:?}",v.chunked());

            match v.status(){
                StatusCode::OK => {
                    /* works fine
                    match v.body().await {
                        Ok(m) => {  println!("body {:?}", m);   },
                        Err(r) => { println!("Error.body {:?}",r); }
                    }
                    */
                    // but what about handling byte by byte?
                    let payload = v.take_payload();

                    match payload {
                        Payload::None => {  println!(" no data ");  },
                        Payload::H1(h1) => {println!(" data h1 {:?}", h1);  },
                        Payload::H2(d2) => {println!(" data h2 ");          },
                        Payload::Stream(s1) => {
                            println!(" data stream ");
                            
                            println!(" size: {:?}", s1.size_hint());
                            // Decompress impl Decoder
                            // Decoder impl Stream
                            
                            // but how to activate poll_next
                            // compiler can size_hint from Stream
                            // but poll_next not found??
                        }
                    };
                },
                StatusCode::NOT_FOUND => {
                    println!(" resource was not found");
                },
                _ => {
                    
                }
            }
        },
        Err(err) => {
            println!("Error {:?}",err);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: try bringing up all the necessary definitions by `use actix::prelude::*` in the beginning

Comment: was not the solution

Comment: What errors does you get?

Comment: the compiler error:
error[E0599]: no method named `poll_next` found for struct `actix_http::encoding::Decoder<actix_http::Payload<std::pin::Pin<std::boxed::Box<dyn futures_core::Stream<Item = std::result::Result<actix_web::web::Bytes, actix_http::error::PayloadError>>>>>>` in the current scope

Comment: instead of crate actix-web http client I use the crate hyper http client, that enables chunked reading and gives me more and easy control about the reading process.
As little dissadvantage is, I have to decompress the data by self, with crate async-compression it's easy, brotli, gzip, bzip2 are suppoted by default.

Answer (score 0):

[`Payload`](https://docs.rs/actix-http/3.0.4/actix_http/enum.Payload.html) implements [`Stream`](https://docs.rs/futures-core/0.3.21/futures_core/stream/trait.Stream.html), so it's possible to iterate over it in chunks.

Each chunk will be a `Result<Bytes, PayloadError>`.

```rust
// use futures::StreamExt;
let mut payload = v.take_payload();
while let Some(chunk) = payload.next().await {
    // handle chunk here
}
```